# Как проверить несколько checkbox на наличие галочки?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, checkbox

На сайте две разные контактных формы. Одна просто в футере, вторая выскакивает в модальном окне при клике на какую-то кнопку на странице. У обоих форм есть одинаковы checkbox для "согласия с пользовательским соглашением". Нужно сделать так, чтобы выскакивало объявление "Пожалуйста согласитесь с условиями", если перед отправкой checkbox не прожат. Сейчас сделал костыли. Когда нажимается хотя бы одна галочка, то автоматически нажимается вторая и всё отправляется. Но если галочка была не нажата, то выскакивает сразу два alert сообщения. Как сделать по-человечески? Сейчас оказалось что надо 5 разных модальных окон с разными формами, значит по моей схеме будет 5 alert сообщений!
Javascript:

```
{{--Проверка каждого checkbox на поставленную галочку--}}
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#send').click(function () {
            var flag = false;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                } else {
                    alert("{{ trans('public.field.TrebuetsjaSoglasie') }}");
                    flag = true;
                }
            });

            if (flag) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#sutit').click(function () {
            var flag = false;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                } else {
                    alert("{{ trans('public.field.TrebuetsjaSoglasie') }}");
                    flag = true;
                }
            });

            if (flag) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>

    {{--Автоматически нажимать вторую галочку, если нажата одна--}}
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var chbx = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not(#qwerty)');
qwerty.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var stat = this.checked;
    [].forEach.call(chbx, function(el){
        el.checked = stat;
    });
});

[].forEach.call(chbx, function(el){
    el.addEventListener('change',function(){
        var cnt = [].filter.call(chbx, function(el){
            return el.checked == true;
        }).length;
        qwerty.checked = cnt > 0;
    }, false);
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно искать именно тот чекбокс который принадлежит форме.

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input[type=checkbox]')
```

И лучше к каждому инпуту привязать класс и по классу обращаться к нему.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно полный пример? Я просто совсем зелёный, целиком код пока не могу написать :(

Comment: Тот код что я написал вставьте вместо ```$('input[type=checkbox]')```